# КриптоПро.NET SDK работа с ЭЦП

Tags: c#, .net, криптография

Как подписать и зашифровать файл используя библиотеку КриптоПро.NET SDK имея USB токен?
Алг. подписи ГОСТ 34.10-2001(512 bits)
Алг. хэша    ГОСТ 34-11-94

Я имею файл в формате p7s.p7m. Его содержимое разделено тегами

```
----- BEGIN PKCS7 ENCRYPTED ----- --- END PKCS7 ENCRYPTED -----
```

Comment: А что говорит об этом [документация для разработчиков](http://cpdn.cryptopro.ru/default.asp?url=content/cpnet/html/08bcd27a-1f1c-4494-a996-37d88776309e.htm)? Читать пробовали?

Comment: Перенес комментарии в сам вопрос. Проверьте, пожалуйста, что смысл сохранился.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил идти по пути наименьшего сопротивления и использовать консольную утилиту Cyptcp компании КриптоПро. Для работы утилиты нужен криптопровайдер КриптоПро CSP. КриптоПро CSP на одну машине стоит около 2 000 руб, а Cyptcp около 700 руб. 
Cyptcp и АРМ КриптоПро совместимы между собой.

Формирую команды:

```
 /// <summary>
/// Формирование команд для утилиты Cyptcp
/// </summary>
public static class Command
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Команда на запуск дешифрования
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nameCertificate">Имя сертификата</param>
    /// <param name="pathEncryptedFile">Путь к защифрованному файлу </param>
    /// <param name="pathSave">Путь к дешифрованному файлу</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string Decript(string nameCertificate, string pathEncryptedFile, string pathSave)
    {
        return "-decr -dn \"" + nameCertificate + "\" " +"\""+ pathEncryptedFile + "\"   \"" + pathSave+"\"";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Проверка подписи. Сертификат выбирается из хранилища сертификатов
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pathSignFile">Путь к подписанному файлу</param>
    /// <param name="path">Путь к очищенному от подписи файлу</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string VerificationSignature(string pathSignFile, string pathFile)
    {
        return "-verify -verall "  + "\"" + pathSignFile + "\"   \"" + pathFile + "\"";
    }

    public static string Sign(string nameCertificate, string pathFile, string pathSignedFile)
    {
        return "-sign -dn \"" + nameCertificate + "\"  " + "\"" + pathFile + "\"   \"" + pathSignedFile + "\"";
    }

    public static string Encrypt(string nameRecipientCertificate, string pathSigFile, string pathSave)
    {
        return "-encr -dn \"" + nameRecipientCertificate + "\" " + "\"" + pathSigFile + "\"   \"" + pathSave + "\"";
    }
}
```

Запуск утилиты на выполнение команды:

```
   private void RunCommand(string command, string pathApplication)
    {
        using (Process process = new Process())
        {
            //Имя файла.
            process.StartInfo.FileName = pathApplication;
            //Директория.
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathApplication);
            //Команда. 
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = command;

            //Не показывать окно приложения.
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.Default;

            process.Start();

            //Ответ на диалог выбора сертификата
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("y");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Пример подписи для Алгоритма ГОСТ 34-10. [Источник](http://cpdn.cryptopro.ru/content/cpnet/html/T_CryptoPro_Sharpei_Gost3410CryptoServiceProvider.htm)

```
namespace Samples.MySamples

class Gost3410CSPSample
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Создаем новый Гост-34.10 CSP.
            Gost3410CryptoServiceProvider Gost = new Gost3410CryptoServiceProvider();

            //32-х битное значение хэш для подписи.
            byte[] HashValue = { 59, 4, 248, 102, 77, 97, 142, 201, 
                                210, 12, 224, 93, 25, 41, 100, 197, 
                                213, 134,130, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

            //Подписываем значение хэш.
            byte[] SignedHashValue = GostSignHash(HashValue, Gost, "Gost3411");

            //Проверяем правильность подписи и выводим результат.
            bool b = GostVerifyHash(HashValue, SignedHashValue, Gost, "Gost3411");
            if (b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Подпись вычислена верно.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Подпись вычислена неверно.");
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    static byte[] GostSignHash(byte[] HashToSign, Gost3410CryptoServiceProvider key, string HashAlg)
    {
        try
        {
            //Создаем форматтер подписи с закрытым ключом из переданного 
            //функции криптопровайдера.
            GostSignatureFormatter Formatter = new GostSignatureFormatter((Gost3410CryptoServiceProvider)key);

            //Устанавливаем хэш-алгоритм.
            Formatter.SetHashAlgorithm(HashAlg);

            //Создаем подпись для HashValue и возвращаем ее.
            return Formatter.CreateSignature(HashToSign);
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    static bool GostVerifyHash(byte[] HashValue, byte[] SignedHashValue, AsymmetricAlgorithm key, string HashAlg)
    {
        try
        {
            //Создаем форматтер подписи с закрытым ключом из переданного 
            //функции криптопровайдера.
            GostSignatureDeformatter Deformatter = new GostSignatureDeformatter(key);

            //Устанавливаем хэш-алгоритм.
            Deformatter.SetHashAlgorithm(HashAlg);

            //Проверяем подпись и возвращаем результат. 
            return Deformatter.VerifySignature(HashValue, SignedHashValue);
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Задать контейнер можно таким способом:

```
CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters(75);
cspParameters.KeyContainerName = "MCPUEpOv";
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/177891)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я могу вынести самое главное из этих статей, если это действительно нужно!

Comment: [как написать хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) и вообще [как публиковать ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin добавил ответ.

Comment: Примеры приложенные к SDK все пересмотрел. Главное, что я пропустил надо расшифровать файл  алгоритмом  гост 28147-89 перед тем как проверить подпись.